# NTP and NTPD Nanokernel

Tags: kernel, time, ntp, ntpd

I had a couple of questions about the NTP Nanokernel as explained here: http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/database/brief/nano/nano.pdf

The big question is how does this Nanokernel manage to deliver an accuracy less than the system clock tick (such as ns accuracy)?

I have a couple of secondary questions:

1. If and when was this modification brought into the
   main line Linux kernel?
2. Secondly the Nanokernel seems to use an aggregated combination of the CPU clock tick (at whatever HZ it is set to), and a clock cycle counter.

> "Process cycle counter (PCC) used to interpolate microseconds or  nanoseconds between tick interrupts"

How does it use the cycle counter, because as far as I'm aware it does not deliver an interrupt, so does the Nanokernel continuously read the processor registry value containing the current counter?

3. Finally does NTPD ever modify the CPU clock frequency, or does it just maintain a software clock where calculated clock adjustment is applied?

Comment: Regarding #2, the most precise time synchronization in NTP is achieved using a Pulse Per Second (PPS) signal that triggers an interrupt precisely at the beginning of the second (provided proper setup, ex. you may even have to account for latency caused by wire length). For #3, which "clock" are you referring to? Most modern x86 CPU's use TSC for clock source, but it's just a counter. Kernel has the real UTC time representation, and this is what is being updated by slightly speeding up or slowing down the clock based on the TSC counter.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Although NTP had this idea of a nanokernel which could be used to patch OS's that don't use NTP, in Linux in particular is not in this case. The NTP code is in the kernel itself as you allude to in question 1*.

> 0: How does this Nanokernel manage to deliver an accuracy less than the system clock tick (such as ns accuracy)?

Accuracy greater than system clock tick accuracy is done by relying on the aggregated accuracy of other computer(s) or device(s). The system clock tick gives how often this computer's tick is updated. However number of places of accuracy is defined in the particular software used, such as the OS which often relies on POSIX standards. POSIX standards for some time structures go down to nanosecond accuracy as you mention.

To see how we can get accuracy greater than system clock accuracy, suppose on my computer I have attached to it a GPS device or some sort of fancy atomic clock. Whenever someone asks me what time it is, I just consult that clock and give that out.

If ntp is in the kernel as it is for Linux, this GPS device time rather than the system clock time can be used in [gettimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) calls.

As for the computer's clock, sure, I compare time I get with the GPS or atomic clock with what the computer and when it gets more than a tick away, I arrange to adjust it back using adjtime() described in the answer to question 3.

> 1. If and when was this modification brought into the main line Linux kernel?

The NTP Nanokernel idea was introduced in ntp version 4.0 which goes back at least to 1998. I think it was in the Linux kernel in some form since at least 2.2.36. [linux github logs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/4c7ee8de956fc250fe31e2fa91f6da980fabe317) reports Oct 1, 2006 as when the ntp code was segregated into its own file `ntp.c` in the kernel. But of course it is there from before.

In sum, none of this is new.

> 2. How does it use the cycle counter, because as far as I'm aware it does not deliver an interrupt, so does the Nanokernel continuously
>      read the processor registry value containing the current counter?

It uses this like any other program would read a program variable. When code using it runs and the value is needed, say because it has gotten new information back, it reads the variable and updates it. If someone needs to get the time, it uses it in that calculation too. So unless the code was written in a really stupid way (and I'm pretty sure it wasn't), no, it doesn't "continuously read the processor registry value" any more than is necessary.

> 3. Finally does NTPD ever modify the CPU clock frequency, or does it just maintain a software clock where calculated clock adjustment is
>      applied?

It uses the system call [adjtime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html)  which goes back to even before 1998. What adjtime does is arrange periodically for the clock counter to miss an increment to slow down, or to increment by more than 1 to speed up.

Comment: *"how we can get accuracy greater than system clock accuracy"* -> Since the system clock is a software abstraction, I'd think there is some opportunity in kernel code to get much higher resolution time without any external source (the atomic clock, etc) -- after all, it maintains that software tick, and it doesn't do it arbitrarily,  Presumably the basis of this is the CPU frequency, which often will be on a nanosecond scale.

Comment: @goldilocks yes, I think this too does happen. After NTP has been running a while, it gets a reading on the the system clock's "drift".  It uses that to predict future time. However you still need something more accurate to get the calibration. (Well not really: you could just make this value up from whole cloth and set that in ntp's "drift" file that it reads.)